# How can we add placeholder for lightning:InputField?

Tags: lightning-inputfield

standard html or lightning input has a attribute "placehodler" that allows us to enter a place holder value for the input field, but
lightning:inputField does not have that attribute supported. Is there a work around to achieve this or am i missing something here ?
<lightning:inputField name="Phone" placeholder = "enter phone number" />

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround solution for this.
We need to make the lightning:InputField disabled and then use lightning-input for the place holder. Then on submit of the form in javascript controller set the field value before submitting.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation), the same attribute is available for `lightning-input`.

```
<lightning-input type="email"
                 label="Email"
                 pattern=".+@example.com"
                 placeholder="username@example.com">
</lightning-input>
```

Comment: i need to use lightning:InputField because it is inside recorde edit form and i am using field api to save the values or pre populate when it loads .
does that still work with <lightning - input > ?

Comment: If you are referring to the Aura version of this same component, then yes, it contains the same attribute. Check here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation

Comment: i am rusing https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation this

Comment: @aakashpoudel placeholders are not available for record input field components, unfortunately.